# Mongodb - Perform calculation with a just deleted value in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this document:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId('asdu7329n'),
  payments: [
    { _id: ObjectId('28sdf310'), paidAmount: 20 },
    { _id: ObjectId('2fsd410'), paidAmount: 15 },
    { _id: ObjectId('2fs32gd70'), paidAmount: 35 },
  ],
  totalPaidAmount: 70
}
```

What I want is to re-calculate the `totalPaidAmount` field when a payment is removed, right now I'm deleting the payment in this way:

```js
const query = { _id: ObjectId(saleId) };
const update = [
  { $set: { payments: { $filter: {
    input: '$payments',
    cond: {
      $ne: [ "$$this._id", ObjectId(/* paymentId to delete */) ]
    }
  }}}}
]

await salesSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update);
```

I know that I have to use `$subtract` possibly in a second `$set` stage but how could I reference the `paidAmount` value from the object so that I can do something like this:

```js
{
  $set: {
    totalPaidAmount: {
      $subtract: [ '$totalPaidAmount', /* paidAmount value for the deleted payment */ ] 
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I can just sum the `paidAmount` values for all the indexes of `payments` but what if there is like 1000 or more items? even if it doesn't hit the performance too much it seems to me more logical to take advantage of the `totalPaidAmount` field here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to subtract you can use the `$filter`:

```
db.collection.update(
  {payments: {$elemMatch: {_id: ObjectId("63920f965d15e98e3d7c452c")}}},
  [{$project: {
      payments: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$payments",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$this._id", ObjectId("63920f965d15e98e3d7c452c")]}
        }
      },
      totalPaidAmount: {
        $subtract: [
          "$totalPaidAmount",
          {$getField: {
              input: {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$payments",
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$this._id", ObjectId("63920f965d15e98e3d7c452c")]}
                  }
                }
              },
              field: "paidAmount"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YdaqL7UAMSv)

But I would go with the good old `$sum`:

```
db.collection.update(
  {payments: {$elemMatch: {_id: ObjectId("63920f965d15e98e3d7c452c")}}},
  [{$project: {
      payments: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$payments",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$this._id", ObjectId("63920f965d15e98e3d7c452c")]}
        }
      }
  }},
  {$set: {totalPaidAmount: {$sum: "$payments.paidAmount"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RDgRFPoSH4L)